# Generate truth tables in Maxima

Tags: boolean-logic, maxima, truthtable

I know Maxima can evaluate logical expressions, e.g.:

```
false and true or not true
```

will evaluate to

```
false
```

This is great, but *how can I generate truth tables* containing every interpretation of all variables?

For example, I'd want

```
A and B or not B
```

to generate a table such as this one:

```
|  A  |  B  |  A and B or not B  |
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|  0  |  0  |         1          |
|  0  |  1  |         0          |
|  1  |  0  |         1          |
|  1  |  1  |         1          |
```

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truth_table#Maxima ?

Answer (score 0):

truth_table(A and B or not B);